# R packages that rely on shared libraries

Tags: r, package, shared-libraries

Certain R packages rely on EXTERNAL shared libraries assumed to be installed on the system, like RCurl requiring libcurl. Often these packages give an error during installation. They are also safely on CRAN which implies their tests and examples pass successfully on CRAN's build system.

Question is what are the required steps to make a package that rely on shared libraries that passes CRAN checks and if there is a way to detect the absence of said shared library on installation?

Edit: To clarify again, I am not talking about R packages. But external libraries installed in the system that the package may be using

Comment: You might want to check into `cranly` which is hot off the presses (only a day old!) and intended to help CRAN navigation by providing summaries and visualizations. At the very least it should help you articulate and manage the shared libraries if you are building a new package.

Comment: I don't see how it relates to external shared libraries? It seems to be dealing with CRAN packages and their dependencies. Is the question unclear?